# Cannot convert EditText text to int

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple golf scoring app and I have encountered a problem when I'm trying to convert the number thats in the EditText where the user enters the par for the hole. The user can only enter numbers into the EditText. It doesn't show any errors and doesn't crash when I run it but it is obviously not getting a value from this code below no matter what is in the EditText. If I set the par to a number other than 0 it will effect the total score when the user goes to the next hole so that part of the code is working. Also when I move this code to another method other than onClick(View v) the app crashes. All help is appreciated.

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    if (parNum.getText().toString().equals("")){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Please enter the par");
        alert.show();
    }
    else {
        //editvalue is a string that I declared but gave no value.
        editvalue = parNum.getText().toString(); 
        par = Integer.parseInt(editvalue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share That what value you are writing in Edittext...?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean, the EditText is empty and the user can only enter the digits 0123456789 into it.

Comment: Where you put this code on btn click or..?

Comment: It's on the onClick(View v) method, so when ever the user clicks on the view this code runs.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking `not equals ""`. So please Remove `!` Symbol from your if condition.

```
if (parNum.getText().toString().equals("")){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Please enter the par");
    alert.show();
}
else {
    //editvalue is a string that I declared but gave no value.
    editvalue = parNum.getText().toString(); 
    par = Integer.parseInt(editvalue);
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: That made no difference, and the alert doesn't show at all.

Comment: Nothing par just stays at 0 and the alert doesn't show for it being empty

Comment: Where you initialize your `parNum`?

Comment: In onCreate, I made it = to the EditText